# Could anyone please give me some hints to solve matrices ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, ring-theory

Please give me some hint to solve this problem. dont give me final answer let me trying to solve this. Thank you so much

\begin{array}{l}{\text {Let } T=M_{n \times n}(R) . \text { Set }} \\ {S=\left\{E_{ij} | 1 \leq i, j \leq n\right\} \cup\{0\}} \\ {\text { Show } S \text { is closed under multiplication in } T .}\end{array}

Comment: How can anyone help if you don't say what $E_i$ is? Should it be $E_{ij}$?

Comment: @DerekHolt You're probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The (a, b)-th entry of $E_{ij}E_{kl}$ is $\sum_{r=1}^n E_{ar}E_{rb}$. Now use the definition of $E_{ij}$.

Comment: thank you so much i will asked later if i don't understand :)